# Switch statement always including both the case and default

Tags: c

When I compile this program, it outputs both the corresponding switch case and the default tag contents, the only value it doesn't print out for is January, any help would be great!

Sample Input: 4

Sample Output:

April
Error

Though I could make the program better, I need to have it this specific way.

```
while (month != EOF)
{
        switch (month)
        {

            case 49:
            month2 = getchar();

            switch (month2)
            {
                case 10:
                    printf("January \n");
                    break;
                case 48:
                    printf("October \n");
                    break;
                case 49:
                    printf("November \n");
                    break;
                case 50:
                    printf("December \n");
                    break;
            }
            break;

                case 50:
                    printf("February \n");
                    break;
                case 51:
                    printf("March \n");
                    break;
                case 52:
                    printf("April \n");
                    break;
                case 53:
                    printf("May \n");
                    break;
                case 54:
                    printf("June \n");
                    break;
                case 55:
                    printf("July \n");
                    break;
                case 56:
                    printf("August \n");
                    break;
                case 57:
                    printf("Septembe \n");
                    break;
                default: printf("Error \n");





            }
            month = getchar();
}


system("PAUSE");
return (0);
```

}

Comment: If `48` is supposed to be the digit `'0'`, write it as `'0'`. It makes your code *much* clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use the ASCII values for it.

Comment: Why don't you change your printf to ```printf("Error: unexpected char %d.\n", month);``` ? That might help

Comment: I suggest this because maybe there's a null terminator before the EOF? Or a newline?

Comment: printf("Error: unexpected char %d.\n", month);

returns: "Error: unexpected char 10." ------> (January)

Comment: ""*Unfortunately I have to use the ASCII values for it.*" -- Why do you "have to" do that? Assuming an ASCII-based character set, the expressions `48` and `'0'` are *exactly* equivalent.

Comment: It's college work I had a couple of months back, which I'm going back over it for error checks.

Comment: Though I should know this... it's always the simple things for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an extra case to handle the stray '\n' that comes from you pressing enter at your terminal. January should work if you just type 1

Edit:Actually I just tested it on Linux and it works flawlessly, there might be some minor differences on Windows, though.

```
while (month != EOF)
{
        switch (month)
        {

            case 49:
            month2 = getchar();

            switch (month2)
            {
                case 10:
                    printf("January \n");
                    break;
                case 48:
                    printf("October \n");
                    break;
                case 49:
                    printf("November \n");
                    break;
                case 50:
                    printf("December \n");
                    break;
            }
            break;

                case 50:
                    printf("February \n");
                    break;
                case 51:
                    printf("March \n");
                    break;
                case 52:
                    printf("April \n");
                    break;
                case 53:
                    printf("May \n");
                    break;
                case 54:
                    printf("June \n");
                    break;
                case 55:
                    printf("July \n");
                    break;
                case 56:
                    printf("August \n");
                    break;
                case 57:
                    printf("Septembe \n");
                    break;
                // Filter out stray \n
                case '\n':
                    break;
                default: printf("Error \n");





            }
            month = getchar();
}


system("PAUSE");
return (0);
```

Comment: You have to wait 5 minutes before you can, that's what I was waiting for. :)